# How to reset Tensorboard when it tries to reuse a killed Windows PID

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

Apologies if two days' frustration leaks through...

**Problem**: can't reliably run Tensorboard in jupyter notebook (actually, in Jupyter Lab) with

```
%tensorboard --logdir {logdir}
```

and if I kill the tensorboard process and start again in the notebook it says it is reusing the dead process and port, but the process is dead and netstat -ano | findstr :6006` shows nothing, so the port looks closed too.

**Question**: How in the name of $deity do I get tensorboard to restart from scratch and forget what it thinks it knows about processes, ports etc.? If I could do that I could hack away at residual path etc. issues...

**Known issues already addressed (I *think*)**: need to escape backslashes in Python string to get proper path and other OS gremlins; avoid spaces in path, ensure correct capitalisation...

**Environment**: Win 64-bit Home with Anaconda and Tensforflow-GPU 2 installed via conda install - TF is working and writes data to the specified path given via the call back

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1) # logdir is the full path
```

But I'm damned if I can start Tensorboard reliably within the notebook.

I found that if I started an Anaconda command window and invoked tensorboard from there tensorboard started ok...

```
(TF2GPU_Anaconda) C:\Users\Julian>tensorboard --logdir "a:\tensorboard\20200102-112749"
2020-01-02 11:53:58.478848: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.0.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

It was accessibly in Chrome at localhost:6006 as stated (specifically `http://localhost:6006/#scalars&run=20200102-112749%5Ctrain`) (i'll ignore the *other* problems with tensorboard such as refresh failures on scalars, odd message on graph, etc.) **and**

```
%tensorboard --logdir {logdir}
```

then shows tensorboard in the notebook and in the separate chrome tab.

**However!** whilst tensorboard reports in the notebook that it is reusing the old dead PID it is in fact on a completely different new PID

What have I been doing wrong, and how do I reset tensorboard completely?

**PS** the last (successful!) invocation was in fact with

```
%tensorboard --logdir {makeWindowsCmdPath('A:\\tensorboard\\20200102-112749')}
```

where makeWindowsCmdPath is defined as

```
def makeWindowsCmdPath(path):
    return '\"' + str(path) + '\"'
```

**UPDATE** 2020-01-03 A MWE of eventual success has been uploaded in a comment at [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2739) in response to an issue that includes the PID referencing errors of tensorboard

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hey—sorry to hear that you’re running into issues. It’s entirely
plausible that everything that you describe is both accurate and my
fault. :-)

> How in the name of $deity do I get tensorboard to restart from scratch
>   and forget what it thinks it knows about processes, ports etc.? If I
>   could do that I could hack away at residual path etc. issues...

There is a directory called `.tensorboard-info` in your temp directory
that maintains a best-effort registry of the TensorBoard jobs that we
think are running. When TensorBoard launches (in any manner, including
with `%tensorboard`), it writes an “info file” to that directory, and
when you use `%tensorboard` we first check to see if a “compatible
instance” (same working directory and CLI args) is still running, and if
so reuse it instead. When a TensorBoard instance shuts down cleanly, it
removes its own info file. The idea is that as long as TensorBoard is
shut down cleanly we should always have an accurate record of which
processes are live, and since this registry is in a temp directory any
errors due to hard shutdowns will be short-lived.

But this is where I erred: coming from the POSIX world and not being
very familiar with Windows application development, I didn’t realize
that the Windows temp directory is not actually automatically deleted,
ever. Therefore, any bookkeeping errors persist indefinitely.

So, the answer to your question is, “remove the `.tensorboard-info`
directory located under `tempfile.gettempdir()`” (preferably when you
don’t have any actively running TensorBoard instances).

There are ways that we can plausibly work around this in TensorBoard
core: see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2483 for a
start, and I’ve also considered amortized approaches like letting each
TensorBoard instance perform some cleanup of other instances at start
time. We haven’t yet gotten around to implementing these.

Let me know if this is helpful or if it fails to address your question.

Comment: Confession is good for the soul - and it it made me smile: I think it's the first time I've seen an "Ah, yes. My bad." reply on something as "big" as Tensor*. tempfile.getttempdir() ?? Anyway, found the .info files at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\.tensorboard-info and can therefore now manage them. One obvious check at TB start: claimed PID exists with TB executable cmd path. Question fully answered! Thank you - for all the good stuff too.